# Can there be such a thing as forward in time (explicit scheme) and forward in space as well (downwind) for any transport equation?

Tags: explicit

I have come across a lot of cases of FTCS (forward in time and centered in space) for any type of advection and/or diffusion equations.

Now, I know this is a silly question. I apologize, but I really don't know the answer to this!!!

Is there any way possible to have a forward in both time and space explicit scheme for any transport equation containing either advection or diffusion or both?

This is a very basic knowledge that I feel I really need to know!

If it is not possible to have a explicit scheme of forward difference in space for any transport equation, then why not?

Please and thank you very much.

Mousumi

Comment: Probably better asked over at https://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: ok, will do!!! thanks!!!